# sqlsrv_fetch_array doens't get the first row of the select query

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

my select query:

```
$query = "SELECT SERVER_NAME FROM AUDIT_Customer_Polling_details WHERE PRODUCT_NAME='".$product."' ";
$result = sqlsrv_query($con,$query)or die("Couldn't execute slect query".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
```

My looping code is:

```
if($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) != Null){                               
   while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
   {
      echo $row['SERVER_NAME'];
      echo "\n";
   }
}
```

and tried this too:

```
if( sqlsrv_fetch( $result ) === false) {
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}                   
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
     echo $row['SERVER_NAME'];
     echo "\n";
}
```

It's not have any error. But while loop crosses the first row that exists.

Comment: This should be enough: `$result = sqlsrv_query($con, $query); if ($result === false) {echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true); exit;} while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {echo $row['SERVER_NAME']."</br>"; } sqlsrv_free_stmt($result);`. And, try to use parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

remove the `if` condition because you already fetched your first record when you call this `if($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) != Null)`

```
   while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
   {
      echo $row['SERVER_NAME'];
      echo "\n";
   }
```

you might want to consider using this instead.

```
if($result=== true)
{
   while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
   {
      echo $row['SERVER_NAME'];
      echo "\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: i modified like you said,but nothing displayed in ui

Comment: $result = sqlsrv_query($con,$query)or die("Couldn't execute slect query".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));;
                           if ($result=== true)
                            {
                                while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
                                {
                                    echo $row['SERVER_NAME'];
                                }
                            }

Comment: can you add this echo "result: "; var_dump($result); echo "<br><br>";

Comment: result: resource(11) of type (SQL Server Statement)  this is what i am getting

Comment: while using echo $query;  getting data from my db like SELECT SERVER_NAME FROM AUDIT_Customer_Polling_details WHERE PRODUCT_NAME='xxx'

Comment: try this `while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, 2))`

Comment: same nothing displayed. if($result=== true) this is not working for me

Comment: can you try to change your query to `SELECT SERVER_NAME as sName FROM AU....` then `echo $row['sName'];`

Comment: same nothing displayed.i think there is no problem in query the problem is  if($result=== true) this is not working for me

Comment: you can remove that one.

Answer (score 0):

finally i removed if condition from my code.it is working fine.Final code is:

```
 $query = "SELECT SERVER_NAME FROM AUDIT_Customer_Polling_details WHERE PRODUCT_NAME='".$product."' "; 
 $result = sqlsrv_query($con,$query)or die("Couldn't execute slect query".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 

 while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo $row['SERVER_NAME'];
      echo "\n"; }
```